# Egerrit SSL Connection Error

Tags: eclipse, gerrit

I have Gerrit user account on https://gerrit.hyperledger.org

[image: Gerrit Details]

I am trying to configure the account in local eclipse using EGerrit plugin.

[image: Eclipse configuration for Gerrit]

But I am getting below error.

A problem occurred establishing the SSL connection with https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r. The trust chain of the provided certificate could not be verified. Please see log file for more details.

Below is the Error screenshot.

I think the SSL is canot be the problem because i am able to do `git clone remote_repo` and able to get the repository to my local.May be I need to config the SSL/SSH in Eclipse but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: fbenoit - nope. not yet :(